# Extract Data From Graph Using Python & Selenium

Tags: html, canvas, highcharts, var, yaxis

[image]

In Inspect Element. How can I extracting the data from a canvas chart As the data points are shown each time the mouse hover the chart column, individually. How can I overcome this problem? Please view the photo below

Comment: Are you using Highcharts library? What wrapper are you using? Are you able to reproduce your problem in some online editor?

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply. The questions you mention above, I have not produce. Please set me straight if you are willing to help me. How can I extract data using the link above? and What is the simple method to achieve this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Ahh, now I think that I understood  - you want to get the data which is used in the chart? So, here is an instruction how you can get it: - refresh a page with wanted chart, open dev console, it seems that the web creator is sharing an object with the data in 'adding series', next - click right mouse on the object which you want to get ( I assumed that it is a data object) - there will be an option 'store as a global variable'  and then use console 'copy(x)' functionality, where x is a name of the variable and then past a wanted data where you want

Comment: Hummm. Thanks for your feed back. Let's see if it will work.

Comment: Quote: "next - click right mouse on the object which you want to get ( I assumed that it is a data object) -" The problem is. If you look at the above image, I can't right click on the (hover " Jan 1990, 858.2") also I can not right click or highlight the each "Blue" column using Ctrl +Shift + C. How do I move forward. Thanks

Comment: Hi Sebastian Wedzel. I am not sure, if you have login into the website. I just don't know... How do you want me to proceed? Thanks in advance

Comment: Yeah, I logged into the website and did steps which I described above. Here is a part of the Argentina Money Supply M2 data object ->  {
    "c": 1455403.8,
    "close": 1455403.8,
    "yield": null,
    "referenceDate": null,
    "date": "2017-10-01T00:00:00",
    "x": 1506816000000,
    "y": 1455403.8,
    "percentChange": null,
    "change": null
  },
  {
    "c": 1490935.9,
    "close": 1490935.9,
    "yield": null,
    "referenceDate": null,
    "date": "2017-11-01T00:00:00",
    "x": 1509494400000,
    "y": 1490935.9,
    "percentChange": null,
    "change": null
  }

Comment: And do you want to get values in the console while hovering a point?

Comment: Yes Sir. Thanks in advance

Comment: This function will show you in the console the inner value of the tooltip. window.onmousemove = function(){
    if(tooltip[1].style.top !== '-9999px'){
        console.log(tooltip[1].textContent)
    }
} That's all that can be done without changing the website config.